# finding joint pdf

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose the continuous random variable 
$Y = X + V$, 
where $X$ & $V$ are continuous random variables with parameters ($\mu_x,\sigma_x$) & ($\mu_y,\sigma_y$). 
How should I go about finding the joint pdf $f_{\mathbf{x,y}}(x,y)$?

I am seeking a generalized method for the above question, independent of the nature of the random variables.

Comment: I'm considering them independent. I originally thought of the variables to be Gaussian, but didn't mention it since I wanted a general approach. So you can ignore the parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the mean and variance do not determine the distribution (and even if they're Gaussian, it does not determine the joint distribution - you need the covariance (which is zero if they're independent)) - you actually need the joint distribution of $X$ and $V$ to solve this problem.

A simple way to do these sort of problems is to simply integrate:
$F(x,y) = P(X \leq x \text{ and } Y \leq y) = P(X \leq x \text{ and } X+V \leq y)$, then write this down as a 2 dimensional integral in the $X,V$ space, then take the second mixed partial.

Alternatively, note that the mapping $(X,V) \to (X, X+V)$ has Jacobian determinant $J=det([1, 1;0,1]) = 1$.

Thus, you can write the PDF of $(X,Y)$ by noting $V=X-Y$ as $f_{XY}(x,y) = f_{XV}(X, Y-X)/|J|$ using the Jacobian rule for PDF transformations (See proposition 1.11.1 in these [notes](http://www.ifp.illinois.edu/~hajek/Papers/randomprocesses.html) or similar).

Possibly related: A useful thing to note is that when you add independent random variables, you convolve their densities (if some of them are mixed type or discrete, you can write their densities out with delta functions to do this).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The usual problems I come across with such a scenario, have independent $X$ and $Y$. So, was unaware of the joint pdf requirement. Thanks for the link to the notes as well. I'm taking a course on stochastic processes and finding it too abstract, which is frustrating since I consider myself really good in basics of probability.